# PowerShell Module Creation

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to create a custom PowerShell module and have included in a new directory called MyModule a .psm1 module file with a few simple functions and a .psd1 manifest file. This directory is stored in one of the locations specified in $env:PSModulePath.

When I attempt to import the new module I get the following error:

```
PS> Import-Module MyModule
Import-Module : The specified module 'MyModule' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
At line:1 char:1
+ Import-Module MyModule
+ CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (MyModule:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

The directory I am calling Import-Module on has the same name as the psm1 file as well.

```
Directory: C:\MyModule

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                                                                                           
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                                                                                           
-a----         9/3/2016   1:40 PM           2595 MyModule.psd1                                                                                                                                                                  
-a----         9/3/2016   1:06 PM           1718 MyModule.psm1
```

I have been using the following resource as a guide:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878324(v=vs.85).aspx

What am I missing?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The directory that's in `PSModulePath` needs to *contain* one or more directories which match the module name. In other words, `C:\MyModule` should not be explicitly in the `PSModulePath`, instead you should add something like `C:\PSModules` to the path, then within that directory, you'd have `\MyModule` which contains your module and manifest.